# customizing TEXMFHOME

Tags: texmf

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 (not sure if it makes a difference) and I'm trying to change `$TEXMFHOME` to a custom directory.  Currently it is `$HOME/texmf`, which I believe is the default, but even when I put `.sty` files in there the compilation of the `.tex` file cannot find it.  And more so, when I change the directory of `$TEXMFHOME` to something else and move the `.sty` file there, it still can' find it.  However, if I put the `.sty` file in the same directory as the `.tex` file it works perfectly (not what I want though).  I am changing `$TEXMFHOME` in `/etc/texmf/texmf.d/05TeXMF.cnf` and using `sudo update-texmf` to generate the `texmf.cnf` file.  Is this the correct way? What am I doing wrong?

If it's helpful, I am using emacs with auctex as my editor.

I have found other threads on here and other sites that are very similar, but none of the solutions for those worked for me.

Comment: (For the default personal tex tree.) You need to make you `texmf` home mimic the directory structure of your base install.  For LaTeX stuff, you want to do `mkdir -p ~/texmf/tex/latex/` and put your personal `.sty` files there.  If, say, you want to put a `biblatex.cfg` file in your personal tree, then `mkdir -p ~/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/` and put the file there.  Another good one: `mkdir -p ~/texmf/bibtex/bib` and put your `.bib` fiel there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why change it at all?  I think what you're missing is that you should make your personal `texmf`-tree mimic that of the installed version.  This is easily remedied.

In a terminal:

```
mkdir -p ~/texmf/{doc,tex}/{context,eplain,generic,latex,lualatex,plain,xelatex,xetex} # for example
mkdir -p ~/texmf/bibtex/bib # put your bib file in here
```

(You should / will need to make the appropriate sub-directories for `bibtex` and `doc` if you want to put things in there.)

Now you can test whether things are found:

```
touch ~/texmf/tex/latex/myfakefile.sty
kpsewhere myfakefile.sty
```

The last command should return:

```
/home/<user>/texmf/tex/latex/myfakefile.sty
```

Note also that the command

```
kpsewhich --var-value TEXMF
```

should return a list of places that will be searched in the order (I believe) they are searched.  Your personal tree is probably listed first, which means that in a race between, e.g., the 'system' `myfakefile.sty` and your 'personal' `myfakefile.sty`, the personal one will win.

Finally, I should point out that your attempts at modifying `texmf.cnf` may have made this answer not work (I'm not sure what you did).  I would revert your changes to the default set-up as it will be easier to maintain.

Comment: sweet, this worked.  I have some questions though so I understand what this is doing....

I looked up the -p option for mkdir, but I didn't quite understand what that option did.

How did you know that ~/texmf/tex/latex is a directory that is seen when compiling latex? Is there a book on this sort of stuff for latex?

Last question. There is a Ls-R file in '~/texmf/' What is that for?

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. The `-p` switch allows you to make a subdirectory (or several) along with the parent one; otherwise `mkdir` will complain: 'No such file or directory'.  Checking where `*tex` (et al.) will look can be done with `kpsewhich --var-value <thing to check>`; try checking for `BIBINPUTS` (which is good to know about for `bibtex`/`biber`.  Try `texdoc kpathsea` for more information, but I suspect it'll be pretty overwhelming at first.  (But it is good to know about `texdoc` as a means for looking up TeX-related manuals.)

Comment: when I try "texdoc kpathsea" I get the following error
"sh: 1: gnome-open: not found"

Comment: @user18641 -- Really?  If `which gnome-open` returns no result (I get `/usr/bin/gnome-open`), then there is something wrong with your system (not TeX Live related), which you should fix.  In the meantime, you can do `locate kpathsea.pdf` to find the location of the document and then open in manually; or do (say): `evince \`locate kpathsea.pdf\``.

Comment: It returns no result.  I'm afraid to ask what that means...

Comment: See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62161/8528); not sure what is going on with 12.04....

Comment: @jon sorry for the necro, but what should I do if I want to add 2 directory to the TEXMFHOME? The situation is that I have my master bib file on my Dropbox folder (in a properly structure mytexmf folder) that I share across computer, so I want texlive to search in there also.

Comment: @Anh -- I'd symlink it with `ln -s`.

Comment: @jon Can I not have 2 separate folders and add them both to the search path? I want to keep the default stuff in Home folder, only personal bib and sty file in the Dropbox folder.

Comment: @Anh -- I suppose so; but you need to modify your local version of `texmf.cnf` (which changes every year) according to the model of the `texmf.cnf` found in the `web2c` folder.  All of this is a lot more work, and error-prone, than simply adding two symlinks (the sizes of which will be so small as to be irrelevant to the overall TeX Live install).

Comment: @jon I found a solution like you said. I modified TEXMFHOME in `texmf.cnf`. Apparently the syntax is `onepath:anotherpath`. I did not know that I had to use the colon.

Comment: @Anh -- Yes, you should read the comments in `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` (assuming your install year is 2013).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your shell is `bash` try to set the environment variable using `export`? In particular invoke `export TEXMFHOME=/path/to/your/custom/location` and then restart the shell.

If this works, you can add this `export` command to the `.bashrc` file and then you'll have it correct when ever you start your terminal.