# TexLive 2012 Ubuntu 13.04 - Correct way to set TEXMFHOME

Tags: installing, texlive, texmf

I have found numerous guides on how to do this (heres a couple):

- [$TEXMFHOME setting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71469/texmfhome-setting)
- [customizing TEXMFHOME](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71258/customizing-texmfhome)

but I have a different directory structure and none of the places present in the answers are present on my system.

Using `locate` I have found these locations of existing 'texmf.conf' files:

```
ben@ben-OptiPlex-9010:~$ locate texmf.cnf
/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/pgfplots/texmf.cnf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-pictures-doc/latex/pgfplots/texmf.cnf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
```

All of the `texmf.conf` files (I ignore the ones embedded in `/usr/share/doc`contain lines that say something along the lines of `do not edit this file directly`). The options provided are:

- `/usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf & /usr/share/texlive/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf`: Go and modify the `texmf.cnf` in `../../` which clearly does not exist. So create it? And in which location, `texmf` or `texlive/texmf`?
- `/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf`: `PLEASE DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY. It is meant to be generated from files in /etc/texmf/texmf.d/` which only contains `00debian.cnf` & `80tex4ht.cnff`. Do I add a new one? Is the name important?
- Go with what is suggested in some answers and just change the `TEXMFHOME` variable as I do with any other variable in Ubuntu (`~/.pam_environment` file these days)?

Answer (score 4):

On writing this question, I found a definitive answer in the [TEX (Live) on Debian](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-1/tb91preining.pdf) guide on tug.

This part explains the best option and why:

> The central conﬁguration ﬁle /etc/texmf/texmf. cnf is special, as it
>   deﬁnes all search paths for (almost) all programs in the TEX world.
>   All the paths mentioned above are deﬁned in it, but other behaviour
>   (such as various size and security settings) is also controlled via
>   this ﬁle. Since many diﬀerent packages can contribute to the ﬁnal
>   texmf.cnf, we adopted a method often used in Debian: We install
>   separate parts of the con- ﬁguration ﬁle into a special directory
>   /etc/texmf/ texmf.d and generate the ﬁnal ﬁle from these snippets.
>   Therefore, if a system administrator wants to change some setting, he
>   should change the respective ﬁle in /etc/texmf/texmf.d and call
>   update-texmf. Take as an example the setting of TEXMFHOME: In
>   /etc/texmf/texmf.d/05TeXMF.cnf one can ﬁnd TEXMFHOME = $HOME/texmf.
>   However, in my own institution’s installation we had the input ﬁles
>   always in $HOME/texlib, which I wanted to preserve. So I change the
>   given line in /etc/texmf/texmf.d/ 05TeXMF.cnf and call (as root)
>   update-texmf. The problem with this approach is that upon upgrade,
>   either I have to reject changes of the ﬁle 05TeXMF.cnf, or I have to
>   change the settings after every change of 05TeXMF.cnf in the Debian
>   package. Here a bit of KPSE magic helps: As earlier settings in
>   texmf.cnf override later ones, I can add a ﬁle 03local.cnf to
>   /etc/texmf/texmf.d and put the changed TEXMFHOME variable there.
>   Similar changes can be made for all the other settings in texmf.cnf.
>   If you really must change as a user some setting in texmf.cnf, you
>   have to create your own texmf. cnf and override the TEXMFCNF variable

So to answer my question, it seems the best approach in the Debian version of TexLive 2012 is to:

1. Create a `03local.cnf` file in `/etc/texmf/texmf.d/` and add my `TEXMFHOME` assignment to it
2. Apply the changes by calling `sudo update-texmf`

Comment: The answer given here is *mostly* correct. What is written applies to Debian/TeX Live 2009, but *NOT* to the Debian/TeX Live 2012 which is shipped in Debian wheezy and I don't know which Ubuntu. In Debian/TL2012 there is no 05TeXMF.cnf anymore, since kpse now reads *all* texmf.cnf files. That means, the best is to create a 00local.cnf in  /etc/texmf/texmf.d and put the appropriate TEXMFHOME=... there. After that call (all written above) update-texmf (as root!) and that is it.

Comment: Thanks, is there any difference between `00local.conf` and `03local.conf`? Or more significantly, what's the importance of the number and name?

Comment: @BT: I guess the names just define some ordering, so you could equally start with `4711foo.conf` and continue with `5bar.conf`.

Comment: The files in the directory are read in order, so using 00 at the beginning puts it in front of all definitions in other files. Other than that the name has no meaning.